# Sigma-algebras on Banach Spaces.

Tags: banach-spaces, measure-theory

I am very interested in counterexamples when cylindrical sigma-algebra is not equal to the borel. I read 
[link text](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32785/cyle-borele-for-e-non-reflexive-grothendieck-banach-space) and
[link text](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24432/borelx-sigmax-for-x-non-separable).

Especially interessted in l-infinity space. I've read Talgat and Fremlin's article about Gaussian measure on l-infinitive, but if there is another method to prove that, without measures? And there is another idea of that proof by Vakhania  "Probability Distributions on Banach Spaces" et al, p. 23 - 24, but i cant get how to prove it exactly.

And what about [0,1]^[0,1] space. It's a separable metric space as i could prove, but what about sigma-algebras.

Would be great if you could give me any links of literature about cylindrical sigma-algebra relationship with Borel or Baire, examples and counterexamples.

Comment: $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ (with the product topology) is not metrizable.

Comment: And $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ is interesting for the sigma-algebra, too.
The product sigma-algebra (= the Baire sigma-algebra) has the property that every set in it depends on only countably many coordinates.  In particular, a singleton is NOT in this sigma-algebra.  So the Baire sigma-algebra is not the same as the Borel sigma-algebra.


Comment: Ok, they are not equal. It would be great if there is example of Borel, not Baire(Cylindrical) set. I think of [0,1/2]^{[0,1]}, but didnt prove it yet. Maybe you can give me other examples? 
 

Comment: "The product sigma-algebra has the property that every set in it depends on only countably many coordinates." - that is from defenition of Baire sigma-algebra on product spaces, am I right?

Comment: And i think of the set {0}.

Comment: Correct, a singleton is a closed set, therefore Borel.
Also, the more complicated set $[0,1/2]^{[0,1]}$ is closed, therefore Borel.


Comment: But why [0,1/2]^{[0,1]} is not baire? And what about l-infinitive?

Comment: Set $[0,1/2]^{[0,1]}$ does not depend on only countably many coordinates, so it is not Baire.  These are comments rather than answers, since they are not about $l^\infty$.


Comment: Thanks a lot. About l∞ we should use open ball of radius 1, and i think to show that it is neither cylindrical set nor can not be represented as intersection of cylinders.